# Azure Cognitive Services RecognizePrintedText vs. RecognizeText

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I've started working with the azure cognitive services computer vision apis. I'm not sure what the difference is between RecognizePrintedText vs. RecognizeText. It seems that recognize text returns printed text even when I send in the argument 'handwritten'. The output is similar between the two endpoints, so I'm not sure what the different use cases are. Any ideas?

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying mode=Handwritten/Printed not working, if yes then following post is talking about it but there is no answer to it so far.
[How to get only handwritten text as results from Microsoft handwriting recognition API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52064400/how-to-get-only-handwritten-text-as-results-from-microsoft-handwriting-recogniti)

Answer (score 0):

I think the difference is that the printed mode is optimized for printed text and the handwritten mode is optimized for handwritten text.

With that said, it doesn't mean that the handwritten mode will only get you handwritten text, but the handwritten mode will likely get you more of the handwritten text if compared to the printed mode (in general, of course there will be cases where this does not hold.)

I have been working with both tools when scanning printed text to draw a comparison and both retrieve the text, although with different levels of quality.